# Get relationship by where condition in laravel?

Tags: laravel

**Product:**

```
public function category()
  {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }
```

**Category:**

```
 public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
```

In controller

```
public function index(Request, $request, $productId)
{
   $a = Product::with('category')->get();
}
```

I want to use `where (where('id',$productId)` condition by product by product ? or give me ideas

Comment: Can you clarify what you want here? Do you want a product where it's `id` is `2` for example and its `category` relationship?

Comment: $a = Product::with('category')->has('category')->find($productId); is this are you looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
Product::with(['category' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', '=', $productId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method :

```
$productId = 1;

Product::whereHas('categories' => function ($query) use($productId) {
    $query->where('id', '=', $productId);
}
```

Comment: Will this not return a product based on its category id rather than its product id?